# Distribution of Coin Tosses

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

> A fair coin is tossed repeatedly until the first time we
>   see H T (in this order, though not necessarily consecutively). Calculate the distribution of the number of tosses, i.e.
>   give a closed-form expression for the probability that the number of tosses in
>   this experiment is equal to
>   $k$
>   for any integer
>   $k \geq
> 2$.

Here's what I have:

The problem requires some sequence as such: $$\underbrace{T,T, \ldots ,T}_{k-n-1},\underbrace{H,H,\ldots,H}_{n},\underbrace{T}_1$$ with $1 \leq n \leq k-1$. But then how do I use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you fix $n \geq 1$ you know exactly what the probability of an event like this is (it's actually independent of $n$ and equal to $2^{-k}$ because you fixed the result in each toss). all you have to do is to sum over all admissible choices of $n$ that is for $n$ from $1$ to $k-1$, hence you get that your probability is $\frac{k-1}{2^k}$.

Comment: Alternatively: we have $2^k$ possible sequences for a given $k$, each has prob. $1/2^k$ of occurring. Fix the kth outcome, then just find the number of ways for the first $k-1$ to be satisfactory, and we also get $\frac{k-1}{2^k}$.